# Binning variable length lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary, binning

I have a dictionary `d` with 100 keys where the values are variable length lists, e.g.

```
 In[165]: d.values()[0]
 Out[165]: 
 [0.0432,
  0.0336,
  0.0345,
  0.044,
  0.0394,
  0.0555]

 In[166]: d.values()[1]
 Out[166]: 
 [0.0236,
  0.0333,
  0.0571]
```

Here's what I'd like to do: for every list in `d.values()`, I'd like to organize the values into 10 bins (where a value gets tossed into a bin if it satisfies the criteria, e.g. is between 0.03 and 0.04, 0.04 and 0.05, etc.).

What'd I'd like to end up with is something that looks exactly like `d`, but instead of `d.values()[0]` being a list of numbers, I'd like it to be a list of lists, like so:

```
 In[167]: d.values()[0]
 Out[167]:
 [[0.0336,0.0345,0.0394],
  [0.0432,0.044],
  [0.0555]]
```

Each key would still be associated with the same values, but they'd be structured into the 10 bins.

I've been going crazy with nested for loops and if/elses, etc. What is the best way to go about this?

EDIT: Hi, all. Just wanted to let you know I resolved my issues. I used a variation of @Brent Washburne's answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your last example shows `In[167]` which isn't previously shown, and `Out[166]`, but appears to be the values from `165`, can you revise & clarify? Also, what is the logic to create the "bins"? You mention between 0.03 and 0.04, but literally none of the data you have shown satisfies that criteria. It's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: Sorry, I edited to fix the input/output. The logic to the bins is that I know the minimum and maximum values (correspond roughly to 0 and 0.15) and I want 10 bins. So actually, I want bins of about 0.015 in width (apologies for not making that clear in the original post.) Also, I don't understand why you say my data doesn't satisfy the criteria. For example, from Input[165], d.values()[0][0] is a value that lies between 0.03 and 0.04...

Comment: Your output contains several values that exceed the binned range, e.g., 0.394 > 0.04 and also 0.0555 > 0.04. So, why would these two values be binned with values that otherwise meet the criteria of `0.03 <= value <= 0.04`?

Comment: Ah, I really apologize. I didn't realize my output was so confusing. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def bin(values):
    bins = [[] for _ in range(10)]    # create ten bins
    for n in values:
        b = int(n * 100)              # normalize the value to the bin number
        bins[b].append(n)             # add the number to the bin
    return bins

d =  [0.0432,
  0.0336,
  0.0345,
  0.044,
  0.0394,
  0.0555]
print bin(d)
```

The result is:

```
[[], [], [], [0.0336, 0.0345, 0.0394], [0.0432, 0.044], [0.0555], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like the idea of writing a function, but I might need to make the bin size `b` different sizes and widths. For example, for one sample, I want bin widths of 0.015 with a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 0.15. How would that change `b`?

Comment: Instead of multiplying by 100, you can divide by the bin width: `b = int(n / 0.015)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` function by passing a proper key-function in order to categorize your items. And in this case you can use `floor(x*100)` as your key-function:

```
>>> from math import floor
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = [0.0432, 0.0336, 0.0345, 0.044, 0.0394, 0.0555]
>>> [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(lst), key=lambda x: floor(x*100))]
[[0.0336, 0.0345, 0.0394], [0.0432, 0.044], [0.0555]]
```

And for applying this on your values you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
def categorizer(val):
    return [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(lst), key=lambda x: floor(x*100))]

new_dict = {k:categorizer(v) for k,v in old_dict.items()}
```

As another approach which is more optimized in term of execution speed you can use a dictionary for categorizing:

```
>>> def categorizer(val, d={}):
...     for i in val:
...         d.setdefault(floor(i*100),[]).append(i)
...     return d.values()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I've said in another comment, for one sample of data, I want bins for the range 0-0.15 in widths of 0.015. How does that change the key function?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the values a set of dictionaries where the ke is the bin indicator and the values a list of those items that are in that bin?

yoe would define

```
newd = [{bin1:[], bin2:[], ...binn:[]}, ... ]
newd[0][bin1] = (list of items in d[0] that belong in bin1)
```

You now have a list of dictionaries each of which has the appropriate bin listings.

`newd[0]` is now the equivalent of a dictionary built from `d[0]` each key (which I call bin1, bin2, ... binn) contains a list of the values that are appropriate for that bin. Thus we have `newd[0][bin1], newd[0][bin2, ... new[k][lastbin]

Dictionary creation allows you to create the appropriate key and value list as you go along. If there is not yet a particular bin key, create the empty list and then the append of the value to the list will succeed.

Now when you want to identify elements of a bin, you can loop through the list of newd and extract whichever bin that you want. This allows you to have bins with no entry without having to create empty lists. If a bin key is not in newd, the retrieve is set to return an empty list as a default (to avoid the dictionary invalid key exception).

Comment: I don't think this is general enough to be malleable for other samples of data. Also, considering I have to iterate over up to 1000 data points in each list for any element of `d`, how would `newd[0][bin1]` be constructed? And in general?

Comment: @Astrobeer3plus I added a paragraph to the answer that should explain what I mean.